# Android - Parse.com NullPointerException when saving object

Tags: java, android, facebook, email

In my app I am using Parse.com and Facebook login, and the Facebook login is working and I am now trying to save the email of the user who signed. I am doing this like this:

```
Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        // callback after Graph API response with user object
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (user != null) {
                String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();
                Log.i(TAG, email);
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                currentUser.put("email", email);
                currentUser.saveInBackground();

            }
        }
    }).executeAsync()
```

But then when I run I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` at this line `currentUser.put("email", email);` But I log email before this and it is not null and I have a email attribute in my User class on parse, so Im not sure why this?

Here the code that comes before to set up the FB Login you should need it and it is working but just in case.

```
public void onLoginClick(View v) {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Logging in...", true);

    final List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
    // NOTE: for extended permissions, like "user_about_me", your app must be reviewed by the Facebook team
    // (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

    ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, this, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (user == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else if (user.isNew()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                showSelectSchoolActivity();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "User logged in through Facebook!");
                showMainActivity();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `Parser.getCurrentUser()` is returning null?

Comment: Try to put ParseUser code in try-catch block.

Comment: @RandomQuestion I added this line `Log.i(TAG, currentUser.toString());` and the error is on it so I think you are right who do I get around this?

Comment: @HareshChhelana could you post short sample, which part of parse code?

Comment: Have you initialised parse stuffs in your application class?, I think it might be session problem.

Comment: @RIT Yes I have my app key and client key initialized in MyApplication.java and can sign up regular users

Comment: Ok one more thing, have you done any logout stuff in your app? & then you come back to this part, check it if so.

Comment: @RIT no sure quite what you mean but I have set up being able to log out the user

Comment: Ok got it. Try using ParseObject instead ParseUser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66176/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-rit).

Answer (score 0):

for checking the response you should always use (err==null) as the condition for success. Only after you have recieved the response from the server and err==null then you can check for current user. You should also have a check for when err!=null. Then get the error message from the err.getCode() and check what the error code is.

Comment: there is no err variable?